# How to create back button on tkinter/or delete all widgets on canvas?

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter, widget

```
from Tkinter import *  
import Tkinter as ttk  
from ttk import *  
master = Tk()
master.title("Learn Spanish")

canvas = Canvas(master, width = 600, height = 600, bg = 'orange')  
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, columnspan=2) 

title = canvas.create_text(300, 100, text = 'Learn To Speak Spanish', font = ('Freestyle Script', 60), fill = 'firebrick')  
text = canvas.create_text(300, 250, text = 'Welcome! What are you ready \n   to learn Spanish today?', font = ('Freestyle Script', 35), fill = 'firebrick')

def nextScreen():  
    canvas.delete("all")

    canvas.create_text(300, 125, text = 'Select one of the activities below to get started.', font = ('Freestyle Script', 30), fill = 'firebrick')

    btn4 = ttk.Button(master, bg='white', command=wordStudy, text='Word Study', font=('Freestyle Script', 35))
    canvas.create_window(300, 300, width=300, height=90, window=btn4)
    btn5 = ttk.Button(master, bg='white', command=matchGame, text='Matching Game', font=('Freestyle Script', 35))
    canvas.create_window(300, 400, width=300, height=90, window=btn5)
    btn6 = ttk.Button(master, bg='white', command=quiz, text='Quiz Yourself', font=('Freestyle Script', 35))
    canvas.create_window(300, 500, width=300, height=90, window=btn6)


def quiz():
    canvas.delete("all") # haven't worked on this one yet

def matchGame():
    canvas.delete("all") # haven't worked on this one yet either

def wordStudy(): #i'm right here
    canvas.delete("all")
    Canvas(master, width = 600, height = 600, bg = 'orange')
    canvas.create_text(300, 50, text = 'Study the terms below.', font = ('Freestyle Script', 30), fill = 'firebrick')

    btn = ttk.Button(master, bg='white', command=back, text='Back', font=('Freestyle Script', 15))
    canvas.create_window(100, 575, width=40, height=20, window=btn)



    def textvariable(text): # translation of english pop up when buttons pressed
        entry.delete(0,END)
        entry.insert(0,text)
        return

    b1=Button(canvas, text="Good morning.", command=lambda:textvariable("Buenos dias.")).grid(row=1, column=1, pady=(100,50), padx=100)
    b2=Button(canvas, text="Good night.", command=lambda:textvariable("Buenas noches.")).grid(row=1, column=2, pady=(100,50), padx=100)
    b3=Button(canvas, text="Goodbye.", command=lambda:textvariable("Adiós.")).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=50, padx=100)
    b4=Button(canvas, text="Hello.", command=lambda:textvariable("Hola.")).grid(row=2, column=2, pady=50, padx=100)
    b5=Button(canvas, text="What is your name?", command=lambda:textvariable("¿Cómo te llamas?")).grid(row=3, column=1, pady=50, padx=100)
    b6=Button(canvas, text="How are you?", command=lambda:textvariable("¿Cómo estás?")).grid(row=3, column=2, pady=50, padx=100)
    b7=Button(canvas, text="Please.", command=lambda:textvariable("Por favor.")).grid(row=4, column=1, pady=50, padx=100)
    b8=Button(canvas, text="Thank you.", command=lambda:textvariable("Gracias.")).grid(row=4, column=2, pady=50, padx=100)


    entry = Entry(canvas, textvariable=textvariable, width=30)  
    entry.grid(column=2, row=8, padx=10, pady=(10, 50))

    canvas.create_text(295, 570, text = 'Translation:', font = ('Freestyle Script', 25), fill = 'firebrick')


btnStart = ttk.Button(master, bg='white', command=nextScreen, text='Start', font=('Freestyle Script', 35))
canvas.create_window(295, 400, width=400, height=90, window=btnStart)

def back():  # i'm not sure how to make back button or make this work!
    canvas.delete("all")


mainloop()
```

I am working on a Spanish app. I want to know how I can effectively create a back button or delete everything on my canvas, including widgets. I saw some posts that had created a class, and use self. and so on, but I am not familiar with all that stuff. I'm a beginner.

Comment: `ttk` is another group of functionalities in `tkinter`. To use them (though you don't in your code) use: `from tkinter import ttk`.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first pages you are placing widgets on canvas with:

```
canvas.create_window(..., window=btn)
```

In wordStudy you are using grid:

```
b1=Button(canvas, text=... )).grid(row=1,...
```

To delete widgets placed with grid use either of:

```
b1.grid_remove()
b1.grid_forget()
```

I can't remember the exact difference so you have to google it.

**Response to comment**

When you delete all windows from canvas in the function `nextScreen()`, 
it works because canvas is defined in the main script. By rules for 
name scope a function will use variables from main if they are not 
defined inside the function. As canvas is mutable you can change it 
without declaring it global.

The buttons b1-b8 is created inside the function `wordStudy()` and 
the references (names: b1, b2 etc.) are garbage collected when the 
function exits. For declaring them global to work they must be 
created in the main script outside the function; all the global 
statement does is include variables from the main script into the 
function scope.

I recommend that you use the same method of putting widgets on the 
canvas as in the function `nextScreen()` throughout the script, as it 
works just fine. The code is also easier to read and maintain if you
solve the same task in the same way all the time.

If you want to experiment with `grid_forget()` here is some example 
code to play with. When you do it, be sure to pay attention to the 
scope.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
field = Canvas(root, bg='white')
field.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')

def start_function(event=None): 
    print('Start button pressed.')

start_button = Button(field, text='start', command=start_function)
start_button.grid(row=0, column=0) # Place the button on the canvas

def remove_button(event=None): # Forget the button
    start_button.grid_forget()

def show_button(event=None):   # Remember the button
    start_button.grid()

root.bind('a', remove_button)  # Press "a" on the keyboard to forget
root.bind('s', show_button)    # Press "s" on the keyboard to remember
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! I really appreciate it! However, I added the code you suggested and it did not remove the buttons. Instead, I get an error saying that 'global name b1 is not defined.' I even put 'global b1' before the code you suggested.

Comment: I added some further explanations to the answer.

Comment: I was able to delete all widgets! Thank you very much for your help!!!!!!!

Comment: Be kind and accept my answer if you think it was of help. :)